# How to validate field path in compile time in Scala 2?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, reflections

Suppose I have a string with a field path of a Scala case class, e.g.

```
case class A1(x: Int)
case class A(a1: A1)

val x = "a1.x" // field path of "x" in "A"
```

I use this field path for runtime reflection. The problem is that these classes `A` and `A1` may change and then the field path becomes invalid.

```
case class A1(x1: Int)
case class A(a1: A1)

val x = "a1.x" // invalid path in "A"
```

Now I want to validate the field path in *compile time* like this:

```
case class A1(x1: Int)
case class A(a1: A1)

val x = FieldPath[A]("a1.x") // compiler error
```

What is the best way to do it with Scala 2 ? I guess it's doable using Scala 2 macros but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is actually close to lenses

https://www.optics.dev/Monocle/docs/focus

```
// libraryDependencies += "dev.optics" %% "monocle-core"  % "3.1.0"
// libraryDependencies += "dev.optics" %% "monocle-macro" % "3.1.0"

import monocle.syntax.all._

(??? : A).focus(_.a1.x1)
```

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#boilerplate-free-lenses-for-arbitrary-case-classes

```
// libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.9"

import shapeless.lens

lens[A] >> 'a1 >> 'x1
```

Maybe lenses would be enough for you. If you really want to validate strings like `"a1.x"` you can write a macro reusing Monocle or Shapeless functionality

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

def FieldPath[A](s: String): Unit = macro FieldPathImpl[A]
  
def FieldPathImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context)(s: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val s1 = c.eval(c.Expr[String](s))
  c.typecheck(c.parse(s"{ import _root_.monocle.syntax.all._; (??? : ${weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.fullName}).focus(_.$s1)}"))
//c.typecheck(c.parse(s"_root_.shapeless.lens[${weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.fullName}] >> '${s1.replace(".", " >> '")}"))
  q"()"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the macro ! I don't know macros but it looks pretty simple. Hope to grok it :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your specific requirements, but before complicating with macros, maybe something simpler like this could work for you:

```
  def isPathValid[T <: Product](s: String)(obj: T) = {
    val arr = s.split("\\.", 2)

    arr.length == 2 &&
    obj.getClass.getSimpleName.equalsIgnoreCase(arr(0)) &&
    obj.productElementNames.contains(arr(1))
  }

  case class A1(x1: Int)
  val a1 = A1(1)

  println(isPathValid[A1]("a1.x")(a1))  // false
  println(isPathValid[A1]("a1.x1")(a1)) // true
```

Since Scala 2.13, `case class`es, which already inherit the `Product` trait, provide the `productElementNames` method which results in an iterator over their field's names. You can then tailor the comparison of camel case `String` variable names to your particular needs.

I'm aware it's not exactly a compile-time solution as you wanted, but even if the `case class`es change, as longs as you can include a check with `isPathValid` and provide an instance of the type you want to validate, this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree that I can add a test to validate the string in runtime and run the test as part of the build. I just wondered how to do it in _compile time_.